# I run a same project from Open Hpi Course. And I faced this PApplet Cannot Be Resloved error

Tags: processing, papplet

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main(new String[]{TheApp.class.getName()});
            }

}
```

And here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    PApplet cannot be resolved
```

Comment: This error indicates that compiler can't see the required class `PApplet`. You must make sure that library containing this class is accessible (located on the classpath, or included into Maven's pom.xml or similar)

Comment: @SaiAungHlyanHtet what IDE are you using (if any) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Processing's core.jar library to your java projects build path / class path.

You should be able to find core.jar where Processing is installed/unzipped, inside the `core/library` folder.

Your IDE should have an option to add paths to .jar files (otherwise you can use the `-cp` flag in command line)

(The above should hold true for the default `JAVA2D` renderer and without other libraries. For P2D/P3D you'll need `gluegen/jogl` libraries, for `serial` you'll need serial.jar as well `jssc` java and native (JNI) libs, etc.)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I use Eclipse. I added Processing's core.jar library to my project's build path. And the error is still remained.

Comment: interesting. and that is when you try to run the java project within eclipse (not export an application from eclipse that you try to run from commandline outside of eclipse), right ?

Comment: Did you get errors listed in the Problems tab in eclipse ? FWIW I've uploaded a test eclipse project [here](https://lifesine.eu/so/P5TestsBK.zip).